# AKS - web api cannot connect to database using ClusterIP on the same cluster

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, azure-aks

My web api cannot connect to a PostgreSQL database on the same cluster in AKS. I created a ClusterIP for postgres, then used the IP address from that ClusterIP as the host in my database connection. I used the default port, 5432.

Do note that it was working when I use NodePort before.

Here is PostgreSQL ClusterIP service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-service
  labels:
    app: portal
spec:  
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:  
  - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: portal
    tier: postgres
```

Below is the services that are running. I used the Cluster-IP of the postgres-service as the host on my database connection string in my web ap.

This is part of my connection string:
`"portal": "host=10.0.....;port=5432;`

[image]

Not sure what's wrong with this but the web api cannot connect to the database. Below is the error.

`Cannot connect to database. Error: Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting\n ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.\n   at Npgsql.TaskExtensions.WithTimeout(Task task, NpgsqlTimeout timeout)\n  at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at`

Here is the desribe for the postgres-service

```
Name:              postgres-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=portal
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=portal,tier=postgres
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.0.xxx.xxx
Port:              <unset>  5432/TCP
TargetPort:        5432/TCP
Endpoints:         10.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: add output of kubectl describe svc postgres-service

Comment: derscribe added

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using pod IP? if not then there is an issue with pod itself. Is there any network policy ?Database pod is in different namespace?

Comment: I was able to connect before using NodePort. They are in the same namespace (default). I haven't tried using the postgres pod IP. I'll try that

Comment: It's working now. The issue was not the ClusterIP but my deployment of the web api to AKS did not worked. I also made a change to my deployment process at the same time I updated my postgres service.

Comment: @RodTalingting can you place an answer based on your solution?

Comment: @acid_fuji done. Added my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work now. The issue was not the ClusterIP but it was my API deployment to AKS not working properly.

After fixing my release pipeline, everything is working again.